# can I post images in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, css

I am asking a series of questions of the user. At the end of the question the system shows a bunch of items. Next to each item I want to add a picture for the item.

Can you put an image into an array?

I have already searched for this, but most of the results are too complicated for me to understand.

I was wondering if I can put all the pictures in the CSS and then have JavaScript change the `<div>`'s id so I can post the picture and also the item?

This is what I thought would work:

```js
var blue = ["question1button1" + "img/ads.jpg"];
```

Comment: Why not add the URL of the image into an array and then create an `img` tag with the `src` of your array item?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to group the elements that ap your image array to. I've gone with **[`document.querySelectorAll('.image')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to grab all of the images that have the class `image`.

Then, you need to loop over each of the images in your array, and assign the `.src` attribute of each of the relevant images to index of the array:

```js
var images = ["http://placehold.it/100", "http://placehold.it/100", "http://placehold.it/100"];
var image_targets = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  image_targets[i].src= images[i];
}
```

```html
<img class="image">
<img class="image">
<img class="image">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Why do we assume that OP wants to use jQuery?

Comment: im not familiar with jquery and i need to place mutiple images, is there a way to do this with javascript instead of jquery

Comment: You don't 'need' to use jQuery. I used it as an example, as I was in a rush. You can easily use a query selector, and I've updated my answer to use raw JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you could totally do something like this in JavaScript, just not the way that you have tried in your question.

What I'm assuming you're trying to do is display a bunch of images to the page from values in an array. Here is one way you could do this:

### Basic Way

```js
function showImages() {
  var urls = ["http://placebear.com/99/99", "http://placebear.com/100/100", "http://placebear.com/101/101"];
  for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML += "<img src=\""+urls[i]+"\"><br>"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>

<button onclick="showImages()">Show Images</button>
```

This creates an array full of URLs to images, and then loops through that array and with each item adds the HTML code for that image into the `images` div, meaning it is displayed on-page. I wrapped this in a function, so that it can be called when the button is pressed.

- `function showImages()` creates a new function, which is the wrapper for our code. Whenever this is run, all of the code inside it will run;
- On the next line, we make an array and put it in a variable called `urls`. This array contains the URLs to three images (mine uses placeholders, but you would replace them with paths to real images on your site);
- `for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++)` begins a loop. `urls.length` gets the amount of items in the `urls` array, so this code becomes `for (var i=0;i<3;i++)` after interpretation by JS. Thus, `i` is defined as a variable, and set to `0`. The code inside the loop runs, and then the code checks if `i` is less than `3`. If it is, then it adds `1` to `i` (known as incrementation - `i++`), and then runs the code inside again. Thus, this loops through each item in our array.
- Then finally, we get the div that we declared in the HTML by finding it based on it's unique `id` attribute (`document.getElementById("images")`), and add the HTML for an image to it's `innerHTML` property, which simply contains all of the HTML which is inside the `div`.

---

### Harder Way:

Of course, if you wanted to do it the "correct" way, you would use a JavaScript `Image` object:

```js
function showImages() {
    var urls = ["http://placebear.com/99/99", "http://placebear.com/100/100", "http://placebear.com/101/101"];
    var imgs = [];
    for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {
      imgs.push(new Image());
      imgs[i].src = urls[i];
      imgs[i].onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("images").appendChild(this);
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>

<button onclick="showImages()">Show Images</button>
```

This code is a bit more complicated. JavaScript's manipulation of the page is based off a concept called the DOM, or Document Object Model. The idea here is that you create each image node (image tag) separately (without displaying it on the page), and then when it loads, add it to the DOM. I won't explain it here, but you can look up how it works if you want.

---

### Notes

You can find more information about all of these language elements online:

Basic Way:

- [Loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Harder Way

- [The DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM)
- [`new Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

Placeholder Images:

- http://placebear.com